# How can we mock an HTTP response using Chrome Dev Tools with Selenium 4 using C#?

Tags: c#, chrome-devtools-protocol, selenium4

I can do this using `Fetch` commands in Java but I am not able to do it using C#. Does anyone has some sample snippet?

```
IDevTools devTools = driver as IDevTools;
var session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();

var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();

domains.Fetch.Enable(new OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V108.Fetch.EnableCommandSettings());
```

When I try to use `Fetch` in C#, I don't see it accepting `RequestPattern` as parameter and moving forward I need to add a listener for `Fetch.requestPaused`. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: So you are performing UI Automation via Selenium (which is awesome) and yet you still wish to mock HTTP responses?  If you are doing testing against the UI in the same way a human would you shouldn't care about the nitty gritty underlying HTTP responses anyway.  Just screen scrape.

Comment: I am trying to test negative scenarios wherein if API returns other than 200 like 500, what would be the behavior of the application